# Is there any way to use conga templates in drawloop?

Tags: conga

We have been using Conga composer to generate documents.We want to switch to drawloop.So is there any way to use conga templates in drawloop?

Answer (score 0):

Nice to meet you!  I'm the Product Marketing Specialist at Conga.  Although Conga Composer templates aren't directly compatible with Drawloop, we'd love to connect with you to better understand your requirements and offer the best possible support for your existing Composer solutions.

Although Drawloop makes a great product, your success with Composer is our number one priority. We would greatly appreciate the opportunity to discuss your goals and reasons for wanting to migrate to their application.

Would you be open to sending me a quick email at rboyd at congamerge dot com to chat a little further?  Thanks very much in advance!

-Robert B.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new syntax of {{Conga_Merge_Field}} in your word documents, then that is an easy find and replace to the <> in your Drawloop documents.

If you are using the old style Conga documents using the word fields, then each Mergefield word field needs to be stripped out and replaced with the text based Drawloop field annotations. NOTE: ENSURE YOU HAVE DISPLAY FIELD CODES in Word TURNED ON or you will be in a world of pain.

However, each field name is going to be different - not vastly, and after doing a few you may be able to edit them all by hand, or work out a bulk search and replace routine that will help. But it will need to be done on each and every field.

Then there are different ways of handling images, and hyperlinks so check those out. Then there are different annotations for formatting of fields for date and currency so check those out too.

But the overall structure and text of your document will be exactly the same and if you have any conditional word fields they will work the same.

Hopefully it should not be too hard.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily convert conga templates to Drawloop

Comment: Ryan, could you possible explain How this can be done or include some references ? That'd add more value to your answer, and help Teki progress.